# Orthogonalization of basis functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Hello Math Stackexchange community,

I am trying to numerically solve the Schrodinger equation for a 1-particle Hamiltonian using a finite non-orthogonal basis (see the attached image), **HC=SCE**. My approach is to first transform the initial non-orthogonal basis into a new orthogonal basis. In the matrix form, this leads to the transformation matrix **X** (see the attached image), and I want to know the properties of this matrix. If my derivations are correct, **X** is a unitary matrix, which does not make sense to me because it appears that the initial (non-orthogonal) basis set must be orthogonal. Could you please point out if there is anything wrong with my reasoning? I can comment more on my question or reasoning if they are unclear. Assume that **X** is invertible.

[image]

Comment: You seem to go from $XX^\dagger HC = CE$ to $XX^\dagger = I$. But $HC = SCE$ so you seemed to have assumed $S=I$ and therefore it's not surprising you end up with $XX^\dagger=I$ as $XX^\dagger = S^{-1}$.

Comment: @Winther, you are absolutely correct. Thanks a lot!